# Class Method Exposure and Property Definition

Tags: objective-c

I have an academic question about Class Method exposure.  There is something that I obviously don't understand about this and would like some clarification from those in the know.

Background:
I have a simple example of two classes named ViewController and ClassB.  Class B contains an array with a method named returnArray.  The ViewController accesses the array's data. I have exposed the returnArray method in the ClassB.h file.

Question:
Why is it that I can access the array's data in ViewController without having to define a property?  I thought that the property would create a getter to allow access to the array.  My example (only exposing the method) allows me to access the data without the creation of the @property.

Class Method:

**ClassB.h**

```
@interface ClassB : UIViewController

+(NSArray *) returnArray;
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *returnArray;
```

**ClassB.m**

```
@implementation ClassB

+(NSArray *) returnArray
{
    NSArray *locationArray = @[@"Place1", @"Place2"];
    return locationArray;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *location = [ClassB returnArray];
    NSLog (@"The count of the location is %d", [location count]);
    NSLog (@"The second item in testArray is %@", location[1]);
}
```

Instance method: After reviewing answers

```
ClassB.h
*/
{
    @private
    NSArray *returnArray;
}
- (void)setReturnArray:(NSArray*)returnArray;
-(NSArray *) returnArray;
*/

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *returnArray;
@end

ClassB.m - no change
ViewController.h - no change
ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   //Create instance of ClassB
    ClassB *classB = [ClassB new];

  //Access the instance of returnArray
    NSArray *location = [classB returnArray];

  NSLog (@"The count of the location is %d", [location count]);
  NSLog (@"The second item in testArray is %@", location[1]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You are calling a class method that returns an array, and you are getting an array. What do properties have to do with it? Properties are just a shorthand for getter/setter methods on an instance of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wain's answer addresses the difference between `@property` and Class methods, so it's worth a read.  My answer assumes you know the difference between class and instance methods, and focuses on the difference between creating a `@property` versus creating an instance variable with an associate setter and getter.

---

The reason is because `returnArray` is a public method that returns an `NSArray` object on your `ClassB`.

A `@property` is merely a convenient way of creating three things at the same time: an instance variable, a setter, and a getter.  It has the added bonus of allowing dot-syntax.

But at the end of the day, dot-syntax aside, all you're doing by declaring a `@property` is equivalently equal to this:

```
@interface ClassB : NSObject {
    @private
    NSArray *returnArray;
}

- (void)setReturnArray:(NSArray*)returnArray;
- (NSArray*)returnArray;
```

This is the same as this:

```
@property NSArray *returnArray;
```

Except of course, the dot syntax.

When you do:

```
NSArray *myArray = classB.returnArray;
```

You're not actually directly accessing the array you created when you declared the `@property`.

What you're doing is calling the getter method that was automatically generated when you declared the `@property`.

Comment: Even if the *dot syntax* is "normally" used with *properties*, these concepts are completely independent of each other. The compiler translates `ClassB.returnArray` to `[ClassB returnArray]` for class methods as well. (I have seen people writing `MyClass *obj = MyClass.alloc.init`)

Comment: Props to both Wain and ghgrif.  Together they answered my question.  I had 2 examples (Class and instance) that I tested. The problem that my confusion created was that I exposed the instance method also, so generally had the same result regardless of whether it was a class or instance (ignoring syntax differences to enumerate the array) being tested. Using nhgrif's code, I was able to determine that I had exposed the instance method and test the property against its equivalent code.  Now I have a much better understanding. Both answers were helpful but nhgrif's was slightly more complete.

Answer (score 1):

`@property` is a shorthand notation for creating an *instance* variable and associated accessor methods (with defined access / modification criteria).

What you have is a *class* method, which internally creates an array and returns it.

That's why you call `[ClassB returnArray];` instead of `[instanceOfB array];`.

These are completely different things. If you wanted to use a property then you would need to create an instance of `ClassB` and then access the property. This would work, assuming that the array was created when the instance of `ClassB` was created.